# android emulator does not work properly

Tags: android-emulator

I know that android emulator is to slow, and I read a lot about that here in stackoverflow.
My problem is that sometimes when I run the emulator, instead of going to android home screen it shows me a an screen with to button, one look likes a 'Lock' and other looks like a 'Speaker'. 
And sometime (Like the moment i am writing this question), the screen just shows 'Android' text and nothing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it says 'Android', it's booting. Just wait. It can take a few minutes.

When it's a lock and a speaker, it's just the lock screen. Slide the lock to the right to go to the home screen.

Comment: Also, try installing Eclipse 9 and updating all the emulator bits and pieces. The newer versions are much faster and efficient.

Comment: Are sure about sliding the screen to the raight, causes the home screen to appear ?

Comment: Yes. Click and drag to lock icon as far to the right as it can go. This unlocks the phone.

Comment: Do you think putting SDK Manager and all it dependencies in windows drive , causes the emulator to run faster ? {edited}

Comment: Currently I have it in a drive, other than one I have installed windows on it.

Answer (score 0):

Dragging the lock downward as far as it could go worked for me..for whatever reason and resulted in the camera getting launched :). Eventually the camera stopped responding and I could get to the home page.

**Update:** Dragging it upward causes the screen to get unlocked. Note that this was on a Ubuntu machine.